# Including a website without the iframe-tag

Tags: html, angular, iframe, x-frame-options

I want to to include another website into my own Angluar-application, but the X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN are preventing this.
(bypassing the X-Frame-Options with https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass - is not a solution)

Is it possible to include a Link (e.g: https://demo.com/test) without an iframe or anything like that?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Were you sanitizing the URL with [`bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl) when `<iframe>` was used?

Comment: Yes, but this also did not work

(I don't know if it is neccessary to mention but the domain I won't to include is different then the domain of my Angluar-application)

Comment: iFrame won't change anything about the cross-domain. You will never be able to load , for example, youtube into an inframe w/o using their api. If you are the owner of the domain where the other application to inherit is hosted you can setup some policies to allow this.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi: If he is the owner of the webpage I'd imagine he'd remove `X-Frame-Options` header altogether.

Comment: I am not the owner of the page - is there any alternative to display the html site?

Comment: Did you try [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) or [`<embed>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) tags? In `<object>` you need to bind the url to property `[data]` and in `<embed>` it would be `[src]`, similar to `<iframe>`.